# Regular expression to split contents of a bracket: e.g. "Emulsifiers (322, 476)" into "Emulsifier 322" and "Emulsifier 476"?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm using R (stringr specifically), and I'm trying to work with food ingredient data. Is there a regular expression that I could used to take a string that consists of a word followed by a bracket and split it into several strings, each of which contains the word + one of the brackets contents?

For example, I may have the following string:

```
"Emulsifiers (322, 476)"
```

I want to split it into:

```
"Emulsifier 322"
"Emulsifier 476"
```

Comment: Can you post what code you've attempted?

Answer (score 0):

If they are all that same format (e.g., "text [space] (number, number)"), then this should do it:

```
myfunc <- function(s) {
    word <- trimws(strsplit(s, "\\(|\\)")[[1]][1])
    numbers <- strsplit(s, "\\(|\\)")[[1]][2]
    numbers <- trimws(strsplit(numbers, "[,\\s]+")[[1]])
    return(paste(word, numbers))
}

s <- "Emulsifiers (322, 476)"
mufunc(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is `s <- "Emulsifiers (322, 476)"`, then

```
r <- paste0(gsub("(.*?)\\(.*\\)","\\1",s), unlist(regmatches(s,gregexpr("\\d+",s))))`
```

will give you

```
> r
[1] "Emulsifiers 322" "Emulsifiers 476"
```